# Непонятная ссылка

Tags: html

Я пытаюсь достать ссылку на видео из html-дерева и она вот такого вида - blob:https://www.artstation.com/47680d73-62d1-42f9-b00a-4132e0a1e935.
Переходя по ней мне возвращается страница с сообщением `Your file couldn’t be accessed`

Также, пробовал удалять часть `blob:`, то есть получалось вот так -https://www.artstation.com/47680d73-62d1-42f9-b00a-4132e0a1e935
В таком случае возращается 404 ошибка
Все действия происходят от лица авторизированного пользователя.

Не понимаю в чем проблема, объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Это ненастоящая ссылка, она существует только в пределах той страницы, в которой она была создана https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: @andreymal, почему не ответом?

Comment: @Grundy слишком некачественно для ответа

Comment: @andreymal, по сути, мало что тут можно добавить :-)